# It is possible to pass the value of user input into bash's command?

Tags: bash, go

```
    fmt.Print("Enter valid nbd: ")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    input, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("An error occured while reading input. Please try again", err)
            return
    }

    input = strings.TrimSuffix(input, "\n")
    cmd = exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "qemu-nbd -c /dev/", input, "/tmp/var/lib/vz/images/201/vm-201-disk-0.qcow2")
    cmd.Run()

    cmd = exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "mount /dev/", input, "p1 /mnt")
    cmd.Run()
```

I want to pass user input, for example nbd7, to both exec.Command as I mentioned.

`input = strings.TrimSuffix(input, "\n")`

`mount := qemu-nbd -c /dev/input /tmp/CentOS-7.7.1908-x64.qcow2`

`cmd = exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", mount, "echo stdout; echo 1>&2 stderr")`

I have modified abit of my code. Any proper way that I can pass my input value into mount variable's value? /dev/input definitely not working.

Comment: It's possible, even your code example works :)

Comment: But it's not working, nbd7p1 not able to mount.

Comment: When you pass arguments to `exec.Command`, each individual string will be separated by a space. If your goal is to mount `/dev/nbd7p1`, you should format this yourself, e.g., `exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "mount", fmt.Sprintf("/dev/%s/p1", input), "/mnt")`. Not the safest way to do it, since you might want to check the input first.

Comment: How about qemu-nbd line part, fmt.Sprintf does not work in that way.

Comment: `bash -c` executes _the next argument_. `bash -c foo bar` executes `foo` and discards `bar` (there are ways to use `bar`, but that’s beside the point). If you want to create a longer command you need to put all of it in _one parameter_ to `exec.Command`, e.g. `exec.Command("bash", "-c", "some-command with multiple arguments")`. But why are you involving Bash at all?! Why not simply `exec.Command("qemu-nbd", "-c", "…")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Code is correct, you can use `cmd.String` to print executed command. There is most likely error during execution.

I would recommend to use `cmd.Output()` and `cmd.StderrPipe()` for debugging.

```
// Output runs the command and returns its standard output.
// Any returned error will usually be of type *ExitError.
// If c.Stderr was nil, Output populates ExitError.Stderr.
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, still trying to figure out, the qemu-nbd part is not readable somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, the code is working correctly in this way.

```
input = strings.TrimSuffix(input, "\n")

    mount := fmt.Sprintf(`qemu-nbd -c /dev/%s /tmp/ios.qcow2`, input)
    cmd = exec.Command("bash", "-c", mount)
    cmd.Run()

    mount1 := fmt.Sprintf(`mount /dev/%sp1 /mnt`, input)
    cmd = exec.Command("bash", "-c", mount1)
    cmd.Run()
```